# How to isolate Akka actor?

Tags: akka

Is it possible to restrict an Akka actor including its children from directly communicating with the rest of actors within the system except the parent (or another defined actor)?

I am looking for some form of access or visibility control. To use OOP terminology I want to make some actors *private* or *package protected*. My current understanding is that any actor can send message to any other actor within the actor system. I want to restrict this.

More details: I am thinking of creating an Akka cluster where I will allow other Akka apps to join it. I'd like to make sure that they cannot "do more" than what I allow them to do.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "where I will allow custom akka apps to join". Usually all nodes in an akka cluster make up the same application. So one application is clustered among several notes. There are no special nodes/apps which join a pre-existing cluster.

Comment: The only thing an application needs to join a cluster are seed nodes URLs. I  think what I need is node role: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/cluster-usage.html#Node_Roles